# TortoiseSVN, How to undo last operation?

Tags: linux, eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn

I had a functional version of code which I was trying to commit to my local branch,

However, previously I tried to make some changes that were not accepted on that branch. So I reverted back to a previous commit.
So I was working out of a commit that was 2nd to last in the branch

Then I made some more changes, tested the program, and tried to commit again,

Then tortoise svn forced me to update, I assumed it was updating the files for the current revision I was on. But no, unfortunately, it Updated the files to the Latest commit, which I did not want, then it tried to merge my changes on top of that, so I had changes that I wanted on top of changes that I didn't want merged together!

Can I undo this and keep my changes that I just made that I wanted to commit? What did I forget to do, was I supposed to stash all of the newer commits?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on file you will have option replace with choose the local history. Select the local version you want to keep.
 Its done. You are good to go :)